# assert_cmd::cargo_bin use Cargo.toml from a different directory

Tags: testing, rust, command-line-interface

So I'm developing a CLI that has commands like so:

```
sandwich [command]

create <destination> - Creates a Rust library at the specified destination to act as the sandwich.
eat - Used from within a library to eat the sandwich.
```

and I'm writing tests for it now which work fine until I need to write tests for `eat`:

```rust
use assert_cmd::prelude::*;
use predicates::prelude::*;

// It should create a sandwich then eat it.
#[test]
fn create_sandwich_then_eat_it() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    std::env::set_current_dir("tests").expect("Unable to change to test directory");

    // This runs the cli and the create command which in turn runs `cargo new pastrami --lib`.
    let mut cmd = Command::cargo_bin("sandwichy")?;
    cmd.arg("create").arg("veggie");
    cmd.assert().success();

    // Now we want to eat the sandwich but we need to go into the sandwich directory because the eat command can only be used from a created sandwich.
    std::env::set_current_dir("veggie").expect("Unable to change to sandwich directory");

    // We try to eat but get an error because the pastrami has a Cargo.toml which is trying to be used to run the command.
    let mut cmd_eat = Command::cargo_bin("sandwichy")?;
    cmd_eat.arg("eat");
    cmd_eat.assert().success();

    Ok(())
}
```

In the example above I get the following error:

```
---- create_sandwich_then_eat_it stdout ----
Error: CargoError { cause Some(CargoError { kind: CommandFailed, context: Some("error: failed to parse manifest ...etc
```

So I looked at the docs and it says that `cargo_bin` runs the command from the current directory and since I changed to the sandwich directory and that has a Cargo.toml I assume it's trying to run something from there which doesn't exist.

I get that it's not an error on the part of `cargo_bin` because it's doing what it's supposed to be doing but is there a way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do either with or without it?

Comment: What is the full error message?